# Local workstation way to access to Salesforce data

Tags: salesforce, workbench

I am running into a question. I want to directly pull data from Salesforce and I found this online workbench which is cool. https://workbench.developerforce.com/query.php Because our company is single signed on finding this workbench and able to see the data is amazing.

However there is a limit of # records. So I wonder how to set up a local workstation workbench to directly visit Saleseforce.com data.

Thank you in advance!!

Mary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to just see data, run some queries? Export as CSV? as JSON?

1. You can use Developer Console (link in upper right corner after you log in, assuming you have system Admin profile / powerful permissions), no need to install anything. Doesn't offer help with writing queries but it's right there for you to use.
2. [Data Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_loader.htm&type=5) if you want to export / import a lot. You can even script it to run on schedule.
3. Weekly export backup (you'll have to manually download zip files with CSVs)
4. If you really need local instance of [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) (for example for security reasons) - link to Github repo with source code is right on the front page. Here's [wiki with installation instructions](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/wiki#installation)
5. Tools like Talend have SF plugins. Talend Open Studio lets you drag & drop blocks to create flow, import, export data, easily map columns. And in the end it generates Java program so you could modify it a bit. [Video](https://www.talend.com/resources/integrating-with-salesforce/) is ancient and UIs changed a lot but the [help article](https://help.talend.com/reader/mhqCkTBnin7IXmJBUJoocQ/S07dRaViPAo71WIlB1L6pg) is not bad.
6. Or use any other SF library in language you're most comfortable with. Python has [simple-salesforce](https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/), looks easy enough
7. Chances are you or another developer in your company uses Eclipse IDE (bit obsolete now) or Visual Studio Code (VSCode) to connect to Salesforce, modify code and pages. Eclipse one was quite decent but there's beta [query editor](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/soql/writing/) in VSCode too.
8. SFDX CLI (the actual commandline tool VSCode uses to connect) lets you [write queries in commandline](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_data.htm), `sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name FROM Contact"`
9. I used to love [Realfire](https://www.datasert.com/products/realfire) few years back, really easy to use but it's hard to justify the pricing with all free options listed above. Free package lets you connect to only 1 org. Also once my firewall complained, I think there's something that "[phones home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoning_home)". Might be just usage statistics/telemetry but if you need a truly local tool for security reasons this might be a concern.

Comment: Hi Eyes cream, thank you SO MCUH for thi! This is so complete and in great detail! I am gonna give them a try and might have more questions along the way to ask you. Thank you in advance! As for the purpose, I try to get campaign, opportunity, order, contact information from salesforce in CSV and visualize in Tableau for reporting propose.

Comment: Glad I could help! I have no experience with Tableau but there seems to be native connector, at least for desktop? (https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_salesforce.htm). Could save you some steps even if you need to upgrade / pay... Salesforce purchased Tableau in 2019 so I expect their integration will get even better. Maybe ask your SF Account Manager for tips? And well... this isn't really a programming question so you might get better, quicker help at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I tried Tableau Native Connector and this is amazingly quick. It seems that default loading period is last 30 days. I wonder how to see say 2 years of data.

Comment: Sorry, can't help with the tool I haven't used before. Try asking in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ mentioning specifically Tableau and/or contact your SF account manager / Tableau support... Can you do one-time manual export (Data Loader? Workbench?) to prime the Tableau database if possible and it could subsequently sync every day/month without problems? Or does it delete old rows?

Comment: Sure. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Final solution: After talking to IT, if your organization allows, API User is the easier solution. You can use Data Loader easily access the data. However if not, the answer will be go through your internal team. Thanks again for Eyescream's help!!!